# How can I pass my data into ReactBnbGallery component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm using the react-bnb-gallery package, and I'm trying to give my gallery a title and description, displayed in the gallery page.

I'm trying something like:

```
<ReactBnbGallery
                    show={isOpen}
                    photos={Photos}
                    onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
                    entry={myEntryData}
                    />
```

But the website would be broken. Is there anyway I can pass my data (mostly for text fields) into ReactBnbGallery component with props? Or is there any other way to do that?

Thanks...

Comment: The error message I got: "Warning: Failed prop type: ReactBnbGallery: unknown props found: entry"

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the [documentation](https://peterpalau.github.io/react-bnb-gallery/#/options) and it shows that `entry` is not a valid property. Unfortunately it doesn't look like there are any out of the box ways to pass in custom text data through props. However, you can fork the repository and edit the component to allow your custom text through.

I saw there's a `phrases` object which could be what you are looking for but I am unsure since the documentation just says `...`